# X-axis with so much tickets Graphic JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am developing a report with JasperSoft with data and graphics with the measure data of a device in a data. This device take a measure every 15 minutes, so I have 24x4 = 96 measure to represent in my graphic. When I display the graphic, I can't see nothing because there are so much x-tickets. So, I would like to paint only a x-ticket every hour. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If this measure is stored as a record (in a DB) and this record contains the date/time in which it is taken, the easiest way should be adding a '`Where`' clause in your report query:

```
Where 24 * (to_date(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') 
             - to_date(measure.creation_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'))  < 1
```

Comment: I would like to have all the measures in my chart, but I want to paint only a x-ticket in the x-axis every hour. I don't want to loose measures. The chart would be the same that I have in this moment, I only want to change the format of the x-axis. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have found BarPlot Properties, and I can remove the labels of my chart. But I would like to paint at least three or four x-tick labels. How I could do this?